# Represent Fare Chart in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, excel, pivot-table

I am working on a booking system for a bus transportation system. I am having difficulties representing the Fare table as a table in MySQL. An example of a fare table for one particular route that was given to me as a spreadsheet document has been attached below. Please let me know how this can be represented as a MySQL table.

Please note that this is only a portion of one of the specified routes. The actual route has over 40 locations and there are over 30 such routes. So, I am hoping to export this excel sheet as it is into SQL somehow.

```
location1   |           |           |           |
0.100       | location2 |           |           |    
0.200       | 0.200     |location3  |           |
0.300       | 0.300     |0.200      |location4  |           
0.500       | 0.500     |0.400      |0.300      |location5  |       
0.500       | 0.500     |0.400      |0.300      |0.200      |location6
```

Here the fare for traveling from location1 to location 3 would be 0.200 and from location3 to location6 would be 0.400.

Please let me know how I can query the rates given the source and destination form the MySQL table once implemented.

Comment: No, Not homework @MarkusMikkolainen.

Comment: @ShainPadmajan I suggest you seriously consider Luc's advice (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11590728/224704). Don't try to force fit a database to behave like Excel. In fact, you might want to reconsider the reasons for putting the data in the database - if there's no business benefit, there's no point. If there is a genuine business benefit to putting the data into a database, then do so with a good design. How to import the data from Excel into the  ideal database representation (as per this question) should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Just as:

```
RATES
location_from
location_to
price
```

And looking up:

```
SELECT price FROM rates WHERE location_from=3 AND location_to=4
```

Will return: 0.400

Always input location_form with the lowest one, so never add 4, 3. Then you get double records.

But depending on your needs you could also work with distances and calculating them for example. Totally depends on you business need.

Comment: Thank you Luc. I was hoping to export the excel sheet directly into SQL somehow as there the data I have pasted was just a part of a table with over 40 locations and there are over 30 such routes. Getting every route into the database from each table would be a very difficult task.

Comment: If you need an answer to import data you might make another question where you specify which data should be imported and showing the structure of it.

Comment: The data mentioned in my question is the only data that needs to go into the database. I am looking for a method of representing it in the database in a format similar to a pivot table.

Comment: It won't work in a database, it's possible but it's not how databases work. You could create a column for every location and then add as many rows as you have columns but when working with a database that's not how it's done. You should create a table like I posted which is normalized and then run queries on it. It saves all information in a list of short records but that's where the power of the database comes in to query it.

Comment: -make some poor sap input it for you 
-make a VB macro to insert the values via ODBC

Comment: @LucFranken "Always input location_form with the lowest one, so never add 4, 3" that rule is only applicable if the return trip is always the same price as the to trip. It wouldn't be a bad idea for a bus company to use a discount rate for trips against the flow of traffic.

Comment: @CraigYoung Yes totally correct but that's not possible in the scheme posted by the author. The relation is always one on one making it impossible to change the have a variety that way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use the following VB Macro in Excel to convert it into a table which with some text processing converted into a MySQL query to insert it into a database

```
Sub ReversePivotTable()
'   Before running this, make sure you have a summary table with column headers.
'   The output table will have three columns.
    Dim SummaryTable As Range, OutputRange As Range
    Dim OutRow As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set SummaryTable = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
    If SummaryTable.Count = 1 Or SummaryTable.Rows.Count < 3 Then
        MsgBox "Select a cell within the summary table.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    SummaryTable.Select
    Set OutputRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell for the 3-column output", Type:=8)
'   Convert the range
    OutRow = 2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    OutputRange.Range("A1:C3") = Array("To", "From", "Fare")
    For r = 2 To SummaryTable.Rows.Count
        For c = 2 To SummaryTable.Columns.Count
            If SummaryTable.Cells(r, c) <> Empty And IsNumeric(SummaryTable.Cells(r, c)) Then
                OutputRange.Cells(OutRow, 1) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, r)
                OutputRange.Cells(OutRow, 2) = SummaryTable.Cells(c, c)
                OutputRange.Cells(OutRow, 3) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, c)
                OutputRange.Cells(OutRow, 3).NumberFormat = SummaryTable.Cells(r, c).NumberFormat
                OutRow = OutRow + 1
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

This would give me 3 columns stating location_from, location_to and price as @luc-franken described. I saved this as a CSV file and with some regex substitutions managed to convert it into a MySQL query.